# How to make native unix socket request in swift

Tags: swift, unix-socket

I can interact with docker api via unix socket with curl command tool.

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/v1.24/containers/json
```

This will return a json. But how can I make a native request using unix socket in swift?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use a low level socket connection to do HTTP? Swift has higher level ways to do that.

Comment: Tom, I do not do HTTP. The domain is /var/run/docker.sock and path is "http:/v1.24/containers/json" (docker developers made path http like). This is not connected with http protocol at all. This is just looks this way

Comment: I see. The `http` in your question made it seem as though you might be doing something with http.